# Spring Social facebookConnected.jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, redirect, spring-social

After successful authentication facebook redirects to facebookConnected.jsp. I want it to be redirected to the home page instead. How can it be achieved? I tried doing with controller to redirect but didn't work well.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/#connection-interceptors

Answer (score 0):

In *ConnectController* you got these methods

```
    /**
 * Returns the view name of a page to display for a provider when the user is connected to the provider.
 * Typically this page would allow the user to disconnect from the provider.
 * Defaults to "connect/{providerId}Connected". May be overridden to return a custom view name.
 * @param providerId the ID of the provider to display the connection status for.
 */
protected String connectedView(String providerId) {
    return getViewPath() + providerId + "Connected";        
}

/**
 * Returns a RedirectView with the URL to redirect to after a connection is created or deleted.
 * Defaults to "/connect/{providerId}" relative to DispatcherServlet's path. 
 * May be overridden to handle custom redirection needs.
 * @param providerId the ID of the provider for which a connection was created or deleted.
 * @param request the NativeWebRequest used to access the servlet path when constructing the redirect path.
 */
protected RedirectView connectionStatusRedirect(String providerId, NativeWebRequest request) {
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest = request.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
    String path = "/connect/" + providerId + getPathExtension(servletRequest);
    if (prependServletPath(servletRequest)) {
        path = servletRequest.getServletPath() + path;
    }
    return new RedirectView(path, true);
}
```

Concretely they say that methods could be overriden to get our specific redirect url. But honestly I don't know how overriding them. I guess you could create a new @Config class that extends it and override @RequestMapping("/connect") too.

If you know some way please write here because I'm on the same situation because I use Spring Webflow and I would like maintaining the flow.

In my case controller */WEB-INF/connect/facebookConnected.xhtml* which throw **Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource** because I configured my app to look for on folder /WEB-INF/flows.

Comment: I was using ProviderSignInController. You are correct. One needs to create another class that extends it and override desired method to redirect to custom page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed the issue by overriding the ConnectController class

```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/connect")
   public class CustomController extends ConnectController {
   public CustomController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
        ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
    super(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
}

@Override
protected String connectedView(String providerId) {
    return "redirect:/facebook";
 }

}
```

This link has [more explanation about how to change the default spring social redirect flow](http://littlebigextra.com/how-to-change-the-default-spring-social-redirect-flow/) .